# How to index using through 2d arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Can someone please explain to me how numpy indexing works for 2d arrays. I am finding it difficult to wrap my head around.

Specifically, if i create a 2d 8x8 array, what would each value represent in this instance:

```
array[x:y:i, t:n:m]
```

Comment: The slice notation is the same for arrays, lists and strings.  The unique thing for `numpy` is the ability to use several slices, one for each dimension.  The comma separates dimensions, and actually creates a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your array:

- The `x` and `t`, are the beginning of the slice;
- The `y` and `t`, are the end of the slice;
- The `i` and `m`, are the step of the slice.

For example, let's define an 8x8 array:

```
z=[[x*y+x+y for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
z=np.asarray(z)

Out[1]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23],
       [ 3,  7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39],
       [ 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35, 41, 47],
       [ 6, 13, 20, 27, 34, 41, 48, 55],
       [ 7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 55, 63]])

z.shape
Out[2]: (8, 8)
```

From row 0 until row 3 (excluding it) every 2 rows, will index like:

```
z[0:3:2]

Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23]])
```

For columns:

```
z[:,1:6:3]

Out[4]: 
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 3,  9],
       [ 5, 14],
       [ 7, 19],
       [ 9, 24],
       [11, 29],
       [13, 34],
       [15, 39]])
```

Combining rows and columns:

```
z[0:3:2, 0:3:2]

Out[5]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [2, 8]])
```